# Placing content above an <OBJECT>

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I've tried setting the zIndex for my OBJECT and it seems that I cannot place any content above it. Is this an IE issue? Any workarounds? I'm trying to display a lightbox type dialog directly above the OBJECT.

Comment: what's in your object tag? it's a known issue with IE, but there are some work arounds.

Comment: It's a hosted user control, not flash so the wmode parameter won't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've specified that it wasn't flash, the other way to fix this problem is by using a technique known as an IFrame Shim.

> [More information on the IFrame Shim technique](http://www.macridesweb.com/oltest/IframeShim.html)

The technique basically involves putting an IFrame between your object your content.

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails, and your object has a fairly consistent appearance, you can swap in an image of it when the lightbox opens.

Or, if the object doesn't need to be visible underneath the lightbox, you can just remove the object and then re-append it when the lightbox closes.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this parameter to the object:

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
```

Comment: That only makes sense if the object he's talking about is Flash (which it may very well be; he didn't specify).